# Diverse voice in my sentence

Tags: word-choice

Do you use "diverse" to talk about a person's voice which can be different?
"I like her because she has a very diverse voice."

Comment: No, because the person has only one voice, although *at a stretch* you could say "she uses diverse voices in different situations".

Comment: I like my friend because of her unique voice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Diverse*** is an adjective that would rather describe a collective noun or a noun in the plural or a noun that can include different types of things or people. It means:

> including many different types of people or things:
>
> - Students from
>   countries as ***diverse*** as Colombia and Lithuania use Cambridge
>   textbooks.
> - New York is a very culturally/ethnically ***diverse*** city.([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/diverse))

In your sentence ***diverse*** is not indicated. If it could be used, I am not sure it would be a compliment, because it would imply instability of opinion. If you mean that your friend has a voice different from others, I would simply use ***different*** or ***original***:

I like her because she has a very ***different/[orginal](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/original.html#C0-2)*** voice.